# Regular expression to replace dashes adjacent to complete numbers

Tags: c#, regex, replace, regex-group

I would like to write a regular expression to replace all dashes that are next preceded or followed by a string of only digits.

See this example, I have highlighted the dashes I wish to replace:

> Scotland Primary School **(4`-`11)** - (PPI)
>
> holiday-castle@cwwdssaa.org **14`-`19** Holiday & Clusters - (FR)
>
> SF`-`**00014**
>
> www7902-az2388
>
> **793902**`-`SS2388
>
> **7902**`-`az2388

The dashes I'd like to replace are formatted `-`

In **bold** is the string of adjacent digits indicating it should be formatted.  As you can see there are dashes in the text that should not be formatted i.e. the ones in the email address, surrounded by spaces or not adjacent to a complete set of digits.

So far I have written this, but not sure how to take it further:

```
(-\b\d+\b|\b\d+\b-)
```

Comment: What is wrong with what you currently have?

Comment: I don't think you actually told us what the replacement is.

Comment: What I currently has is selecting the entire string of digits and the dash, I just want the dash. Thanks

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen just an arbitrary single character that behaves differently when indexing the data. Not really relevant.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use lookarounds to check for digits on either side:

```
string input = "Scotland Primary School (4-11) - (PPI)";
string result = Regex.Replace(input, @"(?<=(^|\s)\d+)-|-(?=\d+(\s|$))", ",");
Console.WriteLine(result);
```

### Demo

I have assumed here that the replacement is comma, since I didn't actually see anything in your question about what the replacement should be.

Comment: Thanks but that's not quite it. The following snippet `www7902-az2388` should not have the replacement performed as the strings either side of the dash contain letters. If you follow this **[LINK](http://regexstorm.net/tester?p=%28-%5cb%5cd%2b%5cb%7c%5cb%5cd%2b%5cb-%29&i=Scotland+Primary+School+%284-11%29+-+%28PPI%29%0d%0aholiday-castle%40cwwdssaa.org+14-19+Holiday+%26+Clusters+-+%28FR%29%0d%0aSF-00014%0d%0awww7902-az2388%0d%0a793902-SS2388%0d%0a7902-az2388)** you will see what I mean, the selected items contain the dashes that I want to replace. Thanks

Comment: Thanks for your help.  I had to modify your answer slightly as I wanted to include the numbers surrounded by parenthesis: e.g. **(123-123)**.  This is the final regex expression I'll be using: `(?<=(^|\s|[(])\d+)-|-(?=\d+(\s|$|[)]))`